# Не удаляется шпионская программа

Tags: windows, безопасность, windows-xp, вирусы

Сегодня переставила ОС (WindowsXP SP3) на ноутбуке, а шпионская программа опять там!) Причем произошло невероятное. Перед перестановкой я заметила, что в системе есть папка с названием из длинного набора цифр. Сразу после установки она исчезла с диска С, зато появилась на флешке, которая была воткнута в компьютер. Я начала удалять дистрибутив setup.exe и библиотеки в этой папке, но компьютер сообщил, что программа используется другим приложением, хотя с флешки не был открыт ни один документ! Потом эта папка неожиданно исчезла с флешки, а проблемы, которые были до переустановки системы, остались.

```
    1. При загрузке страниц в интернете выходит сообщение, что "Запрашиваемая страница перестала отвечать на запросы").     2. Первые 30 минут компьютер работает нормально, потом страница медленно загружаются и соединение обрывается (появляется Опаньки).     3. Даже когда закрыты все вкладки в браузере, увеличивается количество отправленных и полученных байт.     4. Когда отрыты всего 2 вкладки и загрузка ЦП уже 100%. Причем после         того, как я закрываю браузер, в диспетчере задач продолжает отображаться работа в хроме и мозилле.  Прежде, чем написать, прочитала в инете порядочно материала и все статьи заканчиваются на одном: если ничего не помогает, переустановите ОС.
```

А если не помогла переустановка? Буду благодарна за любой совет или наводку на хороший туториал по теме. А то я не могу каждый день ОС переустанавливать)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Скачать Касперский Live-CD

http://rescuedisk.kaspersky-labs.com/rescuedisk/updatable/kav_rescue_10.iso 1. Записать на диск. 2. Стартовать с этого диска 3. Очистить комп. от вирусов.

Answer (score 1):

CureIT от DrWeb
 1. Проверить все плагины во всех бродилках
 2. Проверить автозагрузку из ключа RUN (реестр)
 3. Проверить HOST-файл
 4. Проверить ключи: userinit и shell (реестр)
 5. Посмотреть таблицы маршрутов - PersistentRoutes (реестр)

---

Ой, мне кажется Ольге из МСК - это будет сложновато :)
Но для других IT-шников будет полезно.

Comment: Сложновато будет, но что делать, не выбрасывать же ноутбук)) Оба ответа правильные и очень помогли, большое спасибо! Сделаю все, что написано, что-нибудь да сработает, заодно и в системе попытаюсь разобраться.)

Answer (score 0):

значит вредонос сидит на другом локальном диске